# How to get file selection complete event in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Currently this is How brand list page looks like.

[image]

when user clicks on Pick Image button, i set updateMode=1, making delete and upload button visible.

Problem is sometime user does not select a image after clicking upload button, instead press cancel in file selection window. that time also delete and upload button becomes visible. I want to avoid that.

Also when user clicks on delete i want input text to become empty.

This is my HTML code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="b in Brands | filter:SearchText |orderBy:'name'">
    <td>
        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{b.name}}</span>

        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="b.name" data-ng-required />
        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="b.image" data-ng-required />

        <br><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.files[0].name" readonly="readonly">

        <button ngf-select ng-model="b.files" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="uploadMode=1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Pick Image
        </button>

        <button data-ng-hide="!uploadMode" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="uploadMode=0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
        </button>


        <button data-ng-hide="!uploadMode" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="upload(b.files, b.image)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
        </button>



    </td>
    <td><img src="http://localhost/{{ b.image }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75><br><br>


    </td>
```

and this is file upload code.

```
$scope.upload = function (files, path) {
    //alert ('upload');
    //alert (path);
    //alert (files);
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/cgi-bin/upload.pl',
                fields: {
                    'FilePath': path
                },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                            evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
                });
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert ('Error');
            });

        }
    }
};
```

what changes i should made to get above said functionality.
please help.

Comment: sorry I misread the question.  it appears that this question is about the functionality of ng-file-upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `ngf-change` available in ng-file-upload plugin

Instead of the `ng-click` , change it to the `ngf-change` in the HTML markup

```
<button ngf-select ng-model="b.files" ngf-change="fileSelected($files, $event, b)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Pick Image
</button>
```

Pass along the ng-repeat object as the 3rd parameter to the `fileSelected` function , and in the controller defined it as

```
$scope.fileSelected = function(files, events, b) {
  if (files.length) {
    b.uploadMode = true;
  } else {
    b.uploadMode = false;
  }
};
```

Here we check whether files object is empty or not (Note: ngf-change gets called when the file selection dialog opens and on successful file selection) and set the uploadMode parameter as true or false.

For the delete file functionality , create a function which gets called on the click of Delete button and pass along the ng-repeat object

```
<button ng-if="b.uploadMode" ng-click="removefile(b)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</button>
```

In the controller , defined the `removefile` function , where you delete the files object

```
$scope.removefile = function(b) {
  delete b.files;
  b.uploadMode = false;
};
```

See working demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/zmZwiqJOLVILaCmc4uBQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Prayag. This worked perfect for me. One more thing, How to preview the image before actual upload. I mean instead displaying the file name in text box, How can we display the image itself for preview.  This will be really helpful for me if you can give suggestions on this.

Comment: I have updated the demo with the image preview  , for that you will need to use `ngf-src` attribute and pass the files object into it , in the markup I have added the following `<img ng-if="b.uploadMode" width='100' ngf-src="b.files[0]" />`

Comment: For that i need to have a extra <img> tag. I just want to replace the image source in existing <img> tag. This is my current <img> `<img src="http://localhost/{{ b.image }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75>`. On selection of a new image file i want to preview here itself.

Comment: I have updated the demo , I have done it with 2 img tags but when local image gets replaced with image in server response , it doesn't appear to be in a different img tag , because of  `ng-if` being used  . Also in the demo , I replace local image with a random image , but in the your case that will be the image from your server response